# How to split a string two times with different separators using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, split

I have strings like `"1\t2\r\n3\t4"` and I'd like to split them as:

`new string[][] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }`

Basically, it should be split into lines, and each line should be split into tabs. I tried using the following, but it doesn't work:

```
string toParse = "1\t2\r\n3\t4";

string[][] parsed = toParse
    .Split(new string[] {@"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => s.Split('\t'))
    .ToArray();
```

1. What is wrong with my method? Why don't I get the desired result?
2. How would you approach this problem using LINQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the '@':

```
string toParse = "1\t2\r\n3\t4";

string[][] parsed = toParse
    .Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => s.Split('\t'))
    .ToArray();
```

The @ makes the string include the backslashes, instead of the character they represent.

Comment: I honestly have no idea for what stupid reason I have added that `@` there and haven't been able to see it. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: yeah I have the same problem, I was afraid to put it in a comment because I know this is not the place. But I wonder if it's a temp thing because it was pretty useful!

Comment: @hattenn I think you can look for/discuss that sort of stuff on [Meta]. I just glance down the Questions tab now.

Answer (score 3):

```
string str = "1\t2\r\n3\t4";
Int32[][] result = str.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => s.Split('\t').Select(s2 => int.Parse(s2)).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/dJu0bL)

Comment: Would it be better to also replace the `\r\n` in the original string with `Environment.Newline`?  If we know that the string has `\r\n` then `Environment.Newline` won't work if the code is run on different platforms.  I doubt it's an issue here though.

Comment: If the code runs on a different platform it is likely that also the input text would contain the correct line separator.

Comment: True.  I suppose it wouldn't make sense to include a string literal in the code and then split it, so the string must come from somewhere else.  I think it just tickles my pedantry to see both the platform dependent and platform independent version in one snippet.